# Open last modified file from a folder through command prompt

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I have a folder which have some log files. I want to open the latest log file through command prompt i.e. the file having the latest modified date/time. I am able to go to the folder through command prompt but how can I access the last modified one?

Answer (score 4):

The DIR command can sort by last modified date. FOR /F can process the result. The variable will be set to the last file listed.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /od *.log') do @set "newest=%F"
notepad "%newest%"
```

Double up the percents if used within a batch script: `%F` becomes `%%F`.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Removing "notepad" will still open the log file in notepad - assuming notepad is the default program. The bonus to that is, you can change `.log` to just about any other file type you want to do this with. I'm using it top open the last MP4 file I encoded, without needing to look for it amongst a bunch of dated file names.

Answer (score 0):

this batch script opens the last modified file with the default application of windows explorer from a recursive search result filtered by filename.

allowed wildcards for variable "FilenameFilter are "*" and "?"

```
SET "SearchPath=Z:\path\without trailing\backslash"
SET "FilenameFilter=*.txt"

for %%r in ("%SearchPath%\.") do for /f "tokens=3,*" %%a in ('
    robocopy "%%~fr." "%%~fr." "%FilenameFilter%" /l /nocopy /s /is /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /ts 
    ^| sort /r 
    ^| findstr /n "^"
    ^| findstr /l /b /c:"1:"
') do explorer %%b
```

Comment: Please explain in detail how this works. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.